Children receive the prop from parent but cannot display as a background
I am struggling with this nonsense error. I have a parent component that passes a prop to a child (randomImage), and here is my code. Using the Vue tools in Chrome, I can see that the prop is received correctly by the children, and I also can print it, but I am not able to show it as a background (but it works fine with the same code if I replace it for a static url)
:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${ props.randomImage.imageUrl})` }"


PARENT
<template>
    <div><LoginBox :randomImage="randomImage"/></div>

</template>

<script setup>
import { Link, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import LoginBox from '@/Pages/Auth/Components/LoginBox.vue';
import {ref} from 'vue'
import { randomImages } from '@/Composables/randomImages';

const page = usePage()
const imageUrl = ref('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2956618/pexels-photo-2956618.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800')

const topics = ['dog', 'cat']

// Fetch the image URL on component mount

const { randomImage } = randomImages(
    imageUrl,
    page.props.site.RANDOM_IMAGED_KEY, 
    topics,
    {per_page: 1, size: 'small', locale: 'en-US', orientation: 'landscape' }
)


</script>

CHILDREN
<!-- component -->
 <template>
     // I CAN SEE THE URL HERE
{{  props.randomImage.imageUrl }}
    <form @submit.prevent="login">

        <div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${ props.randomImage.imageUrl})` }"
         class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center sm:py-12">
           
        </div>
     </form>
 </template>

 <script setup>
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'


const form = useForm({
    email: 'test@example.com',
    password: ''
})

const login = () => {
    form.post(route('login'))
}

const props = defineProps({
    randomImage: {
        type: Object,
        Required: true
    }
})
</script>

THE randomImages composable (computed method) return this:

Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

I fixed adding references to the composable file.
import {computed, ref} from 'vue'
import { createClient } from 'pexels';

export const randomImages = (initialImageUrl, api_key, words, options) => {
    const imageUrl = ref(initialImageUrl);

    const randomImage = computed(() => {
        const location = ref(words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)])
    
        const query = location.value;
        console.log('query', query)

        const client = createClient(api_key)
        client.photos.search({query, per_page: options.per_page, size: options.size ?? 'small', locale: options.locale ?? 'en-US', orientation: options.orientation ?? 'landscape' })
        .then(photos => {
            imageUrl.value = photos.photos[0].src.landscape ?? imageUrl
            console.log('query', query)
            console.log('imageUrl.value', imageUrl.value)

        
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('error', err)
            imageUrl.value = initialImageUrl
             
        })

        return { imageUrl, query}
    })

    return { randomImage }

}

